# Swing Java app preview when minified on macOS

Tags: java, macos, swing

Is it possible to show a preview for a Swing Java app when it is in Iconified / Minified state instead of just an icon? Native code involved? Java Properties?

Comment: Maybe you can [edit] your question and post some kind of diagram illustrating what you would like to see.

Comment: Yes, it's possible for a Java Swing application to dynamically create the JFrame icon.  Just create a BufferedImage and convert it to an ImageIcon.  This can be done on Unix and Windows systems as well.